# Conditional Independence on Directed Graphs

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, independence, directed-graphs, marginal-probability

In my lecture material, there is given following directed graph:

a-->c-->b

[image: a-->c-->b]

The graph can be represented by the factorization:
$$p(a,b,c)=p(a)p(c|a)p(b|c)$$

The task is to check, whether $a$ and $b$ are independent, if c is unobserved. So to get $p(a,b)$ we marginalize $p(a,b,c)$ over $c$:
$$p(a,b)=\sum_{c}p(a)p(c|a)p(b|c)=p(a)\sum_{c}p(c|a)p(b|c)=p(a)p(b|a)\neq p(a)p(b)$$

I tried for hours to calculate why $\sum_{c}p(c|a)p(b|c)=p(b|a)$, but I just can't get it. Is there a rule or something that I'm missing? Or is this step not as trivial as the lecture notes make it out to be?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The given graph does not imply that $a$ and $b$ are marginally independent. Instead of trying to prove they're independent, try to find a counterexample.

Comment: Whenever you are "**checking** whether it is something," and having trouble proving that it *is*, then consider that maybe it *is not* (always), and try showing that instead.